# Writing to a file in java

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I am trying to create and write to a java file using print writer.
I looked at [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/java-how-to-create-and-write-to-a-file)
I am unable to write to the file. The file is created but with no text
Can someone please tell me what I missed?
Thanks

```
static void createFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    String filename = "nothign.txt";
    FileOutputStream connection1;
    connection1 = new FileOutputStream( filename );
    PrintWriter printnothing = null;

    printnothing = new PrintWriter(connection1);
    printnothing.printf("/nnewline writesomething/n exo");
    printnothing.println("trying to write something");
}// createFile Method
```

Comment: Use `\n` instead of `/n` for a newline character.

Comment: whoops, thanks for the catch

Comment: is there any performance benefit (or any benefit) for initializing the variable as null and then assigning it a `new` object. than doing both in the same line?

Comment: No. There isn't that I am aware of.

Comment: incidentally  printf line seperators don't work with PrintWriter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to close your PrintWriter in order to flush the contents to the file. Try adding this to the end of your code:

```
printnothing.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush.

1. You can automatically flush if you supply `true` as second parameter
   in the constructor.
2. You can flush manually by calling `flush()`.
3. You can flush implicitly by closing the stream with `.close()`.

You also need to close the stream so the file is released.

1. You can do it with explicitly calling .close() when you're done with it.
2. You can take advantage of Java 7's try-with-resource feature with the following syntax..

Example:

```
try (PrintWriter printnothing = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("nothign.txt"))) {
     printnothing.printf("stuff"); 
     printnothing.println("stuff");
} catch(IOException e) { 
     e.printStacktrace(); // We don't have to close it here, and neither do have to in a finally block - it's handled for us 
}
```

Comment: IMO there is far too much information here that is irrelevant to the OP's (stated) requirements.  He just wants to know why there is no output.

Comment: Thanks Xabster, thorough answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call either `printnothig.close()` (which is what you should do assuming you won't be using that object to print again) or `printnothing.flush()`

Comment: He needs to close it. It's a local variable. No-one else can close it. Otherwise there is a resource leak.

Comment: You're correct; I wasn't paying close enough attention, thought it was a class variable.